# TCPDF integration Codeigniter constructor only use default parameters

Tags: codeigniter, parameters, constructor, integration, tcpdf

I already integrate the library. I created the class Pdf:

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/tcpdf/tcpdf.php';

class Pdf extends TCPDF { 
    public function __construct($params) { 
        parent::__construct(); 
    }
}
```

But when I call the constructor with other parameters, the constructor only use the default params.

```
$this->load->library('pdf');
$pdf = new Pdf('L', 'mm', array(216, 330), true, 'UTF-8', false);
```

But if I change the class Pdf for TCPDF works fine.

```
$this->load->library('pdf');
$pdf = new TCPDF('L', 'mm', array(216, 330), true, 'UTF-8', false);
```

The problem is I want to change the header and its necessarily to create a new class who extends TCPDF with the new header information. And I cant call the constructor of this class (Pdf class) with custom params.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must of course pass the parameters to the parent class. And note that TCPDF expects a long list of separate parameters, not an array. One way to solve this would be the invokation with `call_user_func_array`:

```
class Pdf extends TCPDF {
    public function __construct() { 
        call_user_func_array('parent::__construct', func_get_args());
    }
}
```

Note that the `$params` parameter was removed from `Pdf::__construct`, because it doesn't make sense anyway. Instead, `func_get_args()` will collect an arbitrary number of parameters and pass them to the parent constructor.

Of course, if `$params` is an array which already holds the values to be passed to TCPDF, you can use that one instead of `func_get_args()`. But make sure that the array values are in the correct order.